# Custom IPv6 network and security risks

Tags: server, tunneling, ipv6

[image: Custom network]
I draw a custom network (I would use that for developing and testing, my ISP does not support IPv6), there IPv4 and IPv6 are present.
'A' device has firewall: incoming blocked, only accept access (SSH) from 192.168.0.0/16 (private network)
'B' device has default firewall settings: incoming blocked
'C' device has firewall: incoming blocked, only accept access (SSH) from 192.168.0.0/16 (private network), 80 and 443 ports open from IPv6
'D' device has default firewall settings: incoming blocked

The 'A' and 'C' device use Ubuntu LTS server. The IPv4 private network is created by DHCP server of Router ('A' and 'C' devices have fix private IP address). Custom DNS server (Google) is used at end points. The IPv6 tunner broker will be Hurricane Electric.

**Is it posible to use only IPv4 connection (instead of IPv6) to update the linux ('A', 'C') servers?**

**Should I use other DNS server? Should I use DHCPv6?**

**Are there any security risk? Can I prevent attack by settings on 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D' if 4G router is vulnerable?**